# Why was this off-topic flag declined for a question with so many downvotes?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743848/sql-duplicated-rows-selection-without-using-having) as off-topic because it was a code-writing request.

[image: Screenshot of question]

The question itself has -8 net downvotes and doesn't show any research or an attempt at a solution. The flag was declined... I'm not sure why, since it certainly appears a though the community regards this as a non-productive question.

Comment: When you flag "in need of moderator intervention" for a situation that is easily handled by the community, your flag will be declined by a mod.  And other flags can be declined by users with enough rep disagreeing with it, even when your flag is spot on.  It's rare, but happens.

Comment: because downvotes have nothing to do with the on-topic-ness of a post?

Comment: @Kevin I realize that, but it's evidence to the possibility that a post is off-topic... at the very least, a lot of downvotes warrants raising some questions of whether the post is suitable for the site, regardless of whether it gets flagged or not.

Comment: I don't think it's evidence of that at all though. Voting is for quality. A post can be very low quality while still being on topic, the same way a post can be of very high quality and upvoted but still get closed due to being off topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The question itself has -8 net downvotes and doesn't show any research or an attempt at a solution.

That's not a close reason, so of course it'll be declined.  That *is* a reason to downvote a question, which is why it has so many downvotes.

If you flag the question for closure with a valid close reason that actually applies to it, then it can be closed.

Comment: Also the [close review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/10225042) felt it should remain open which declined the flag.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the purpose of flags. There is one flag which states: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. **See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**" (emphasis mine). I was under the impression that questions that basically just asked for us to write code for them were not acceptable on SO - is that not the case?

Comment: (Not trying to be combative, just seriously trying to understand what is appropriate to flag)

Comment: @MageXy 1) you didn't say that that was how you flagged the post; you said that you flagged it for the reason I quoted; big difference 2) The question *isn't* asking how to debug code; he has no code to debug.

Comment: @Servy: Is there a better flag to use for code writing requests? I see them fairly regularly but I can't find a flag that looks more appropriate than the one I've mentioned (which admittedly isn't a perfect fit either).

Comment: @MageXy That a question is a code writing request doesn't automatically make it close worthy.  A large portion of them will have some close reason apply to them, but you should be using that close reason *because it applies to the question*, not just because "this is what I do for all code requests".

Comment: @Servy: Thanks for the explanation. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: I am not suggesting closing this question, but why is this question not closed because of code requesting or something like "do my work"?

Comment: @amuse Because that's not a close reason.